# Use python running in HDI to access blob storage

Tags: python, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I am writing a pig embedded python script which is up and running in HDInsights.

> I am attempting to add to the python part a conditional block which
>   checks for a path in blob storage (e.g. wasb://container@account/path)
>   and updates variables based on this check.

It seems that the standard os.path.exists cannot access blob storage (or I am using the wrong format for the file paths). Anybody have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WASB is an HDFS compatible filesystem, so Hadoop and things that run inside Hadoop (hive, mapreduce, etc.,) know how to use it; Python and other OS things don't.

If you know the default storage account/container used for the HDInsight cluster, you could use the https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python to check whether the blob exists in the container that way. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/ should have information on using it to access blobs.

Comment: The mentioned azure sdk for python should do the job, accessing blob storage using these modules is easy. The challenge could be accessing non-standard python modules from your cluster nodes. This article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2014/03/03/how-to-deploy-a-python-module-to-windows-azure-hdinsight.aspx could be a starting point.

Comment: If you're using Windows-based HDInsight clusters, you'll probably need the blog post mentioned above. If you're using the Linux-based preview, you can connect to the head node using SSH, then connect to the worker nodes from there (using SSH,) and install whatever you need.